# Produce new data dynamically based on existing data

Tags: sql, t-sql

Having a hard time trying to explain what I'm trying to achieve just using words...

I'm working with two tables here.  One has a list of customers with their unqiue reference.  The second a table (datatable) which holds some generic data which is linked to the customer by their reference.

What I'd like to is copy each existing row in the datatable and replace the customer reference with every customer.

Example.

```
CustomerTable
ID, Name, Address
001, ABC, ABC
002, DEF, DEF
003, GHI, GHI

DataTable (before)
ID, Detail1, Detail2, Detail3
001, A, B, C
001, D, E, F
001, G, H, I

DataTable (after)
ID, Detail1, Detail2, Detail3
001, A, B, C
001, D, E, F
001, G, H, I
002, A, B, C
002, D, E, F
002, G, H, I
003, A, B, C
003, D, E, F
003, G, H, I
```

This will update thousands of rows so I don't know what the most efficient way to do this.  Looking at it like a programmer I want to use arrays and loops but this probably isn't the best approach in T-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you are actually just looking for a cross joined set of results which can then created into a table.

Based on your example:

```
SELECT CustomerTable.ID, DataTable.Detail1, DataTable.Detail2, DataTable.Detail3 
INTO New_DataTable
FROM CustomerTable
CROSS JOIN DataTable
```

This will create a new table (New_DataTable) with the correct data. You could then just rename away the old table and rename the new one to the original name. The sp_rename stored procedure can be used to do this.

```
sp_rename DataTable, Original_DataTable
sp_rename New_DataTable, DataTable
```

You must guarantee that no one will be updating the existing DataTable to do the switch out.

Comment: This is perfect.  I've been able to build on your example and get it to work as required.  Still plenty to do but you've set me on the right path.  Thank you very much.